# Why it is central in $\mathbb {Z}[G]$?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, representation-theory

In proposition 4.17, why is $P$ an central element?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P$ is central because $gPg^{-1}=P$ for all $g\in G$ due to the fact that conjugation permutes the elements of a conjugacy class.